# Wordnet edit tree structure

Tags: nlp, wordnet

I'm developing an application that uses the Wordnet conceptual hierarchy for its operation. I found that some words I need are missing in the database. Is there an API or tool, or any other way I can insert new words, edit the structure etc.? (I'm using Wordnet 3.0.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [RDF version of Wordnet](http://semanticweb.cs.vu.nl/lod/wn30/) it's easy to add new synsets, relationships, words etc.